# Pagination: replace pages number to the number of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I need to replace number of pages with the number of elements. I have 5 elements on every page and I want to to replace the pages from 1, 2, 3 to 5, 10, 15 etc. This is plugin for reviews in wordpress website. Can I do this with jQuery?

```html
<div class="reviews_pagination">
    <div class="reviews_pagination_page">Page 1 of 3: </div>
    <div data-page="1" class="reivews_a reivews_current">1</div>
    <div data-page="2" class="reivews_a ">2</div>  
    <div data-page="3" class="reivews_a ">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need to put your code in a comment, all relevant code should be placed in the question.

Comment: Sorry I deleted it

Answer (score 0):

a small change in your HTML

```
<div class="reviews_pagination">
    <div class="reviews_pagination_page">Page <span class="firstpage"></span> of <span class="lastpage"></span>: </div>
    <div data-page="1" class="reivews_a reivews_current">1</div>
    <div data-page="2" class="reivews_a ">2</div>  
    <div data-page="3" class="reivews_a ">3</div>
</div>
```

use this jquery

```
$('.firstpage').text($('.reviews_pagination .reivews_a').first().data('page'));
$('.lastpage').text($('.reviews_pagination .reivews_a').last().data('page'));
```

this will change the firstpage and lastpage span contents depends on the page.